# Find all integers $(x, y)$ / $1 + 2^x + 2^{2x + 1} = y^2$

Tags: number-theory

kindly, can anyone explain me the last part of Joffan's proof starting from: "Clearly we cannot have $k=2^{x-2}$ or $k+1=2^{x-2}$ so we need $(2^{x+1}+1)$ to split into (odd) factors r,s such that $2^{x-2}r = s\pm 1$....to the end" . Honestly, I was lost in this part.
The link: [Find all integers $(x, y)$ such that $1 + 2^x + 2^{2x + 1} = y^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113767/find-all-integers-x-y-such-that-1-2x-22x-1-y2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will find if you substitute those values for $k$ or $k+1$ that the equation cannot hold. Only one of $k$ and $k+1$ can be even, but since it can't be a power of $2$ it must have an odd factor.